# issue in integrating okta with my UI (angular 9) and backend(spring boot)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, okta, okta-api

integrating okta with my UI (angular 9) and backend(spring boot) facing issues when deplying both in my tomcat as UI is getting redirected again and again after logging into okta. configured as single page application in oktaLocalhost:4200 is redirecting properly(angular server)
But not with localhost:8080 after building my UI code and deploying it in tomcat.

Attaching Implicit/callback with my URL is not throwing any issues with angular server but when deploying in tomcat it's giving redirect_uri issue.

Comment: Are you running your apps separately? Or are you packaging them together? Can you include a screenshot of the error you're seeing in your question, please.

Comment: Hi Matt , i am running them together in my tomcat instance and I followed this documentation https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/13/angular-8-spring-boot-2. I will be attaching the screenshot

Comment: I wrote that tutorial and there's nothing in it about combining the apps together. That's why I asked. You could run your Spring Boot app in Tomcat, but you'll likely be running your Angular app with `ng serve` or from some sort of web server. There are ways to combine the two, but it'll involve ripping out Okta from Angular and letting Spring Boot handle your OAuth flows. I have a blog post I'm writing on that now, but it'll likely take a few weeks before it's published.

Comment: I'm building my angular app via ng build and creating .war file for backend deployment is there a way to integrate okta for these? And thanks Matt I'll be eagerly waiting for your blog post.

Comment: Are you somehow including the output of `ng build` in your WAR file? If so, it doesn't make sense to have Okta in your Angular app. You can leverage Spring Security to convey the authentication status. I just gave a [brief example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818975/keep-user-logged-in-on-angular-screen-if-user-was-already-authenticated-in-java/61819258#61819258) in another answer. If you need more details, see [Deploy Your Secure Spring Boot + Angular PWA as a Single Artifact](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/18/spring-boot-angular-auth-code-flow) or wait for my blog post.

Comment: No Matt, i'am not although I'm running them both in same server.Thanks for the help I'll be waiting for your blog and try to dig in deeper.